# VSCode "Move editor into next group" keymap not working on Windows

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VSCode, the keyboar shortcut for ""Move editor into next/previous group" is:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>RightArrow</kbd>/<kbd>LeftArrow</kbd>

However this keymap also changes the orientation of the screen to its side...

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Just fount out it's my graphics card hotkey... Disabled it and all's working.